# symfony3 not redirecting on ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, redirect

I'm trying to submit a form via ajax on Symfony3, but I have a problem because sometimes it does not redirect to "ShowView" after saving the data.

If the entered data is valid in the first ajax call it saves the data, but it does not redirect.

If the entered data is invalid in the first ajax call it refresh the form correctly then I correct the data and submit it again, this time it saves the data and it redirects correctly.

I do not know why sometimes it redirects correcty and others it does not. Can somebady help me, plaese.

This is my entity:

```
<?php

namespace PruebaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Prueba
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="prueba")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PruebaBundle\Repository\PruebaRepository")
 */
class Prueba
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Ingresar un valor")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 2,
     *      max = 10,
     *      minMessage = "La descripcion debe tener un minimo de {{ limit }} caracteres de longitud",
     *      maxMessage = "La descripcion debe tener un maximo de {{ limit }} caracteres de longitud"
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="descripcion", type="string", length=100)
     *
     */
    private $descripcion;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set descripcion
     *
     * @param string $descripcion
     *
     * @return Prueba
     */
    public function setDescripcion($descripcion)
    {
        $this->descripcion = $descripcion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descripcion
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescripcion()
    {
        return $this->descripcion;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace PruebaBundle\Controller;

use PruebaBundle\Entity\Prueba;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Prueba controller.
 *
 * @Route("prueba")
 */
class PruebaController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Lists all prueba entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="prueba_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $pruebas = $em->getRepository('PruebaBundle:Prueba')->findAll();

        return $this->render('PruebaBundle:Prueba:index.html.twig', array(
                    'pruebas' => $pruebas,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new prueba entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="prueba_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request) {
        $prueba = new Prueba();
        $form = $this->createForm('PruebaBundle\Form\PruebaType', $prueba);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($prueba);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('prueba_show', array('id' => $prueba->getId()));

        }

        return $this->render('PruebaBundle:Prueba:new.html.twig', array(
                    'prueba' => $prueba,
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a prueba entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="prueba_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(Prueba $prueba) {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($prueba);

        return $this->render('PruebaBundle:Prueba:show.html.twig', array(
                    'prueba' => $prueba,
                    'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing prueba entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="prueba_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Prueba $prueba) {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($prueba);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('PruebaBundle\Form\PruebaType', $prueba);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('prueba_edit', array('id' => $prueba->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('PruebaBundle:Prueba:edit.html.twig', array(
                    'prueba' => $prueba,
                    'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
                    'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a prueba entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="prueba_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, Prueba $prueba) {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($prueba);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($prueba);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('prueba_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a prueba entity.
     *
     * @param Prueba $prueba The prueba entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(Prueba $prueba) {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
                        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('prueba_delete', array('id' => $prueba->getId())))
                        ->setMethod('DELETE')
                        ->getForm()
        ;
    }

}
```

FormType:

```
<?php

namespace PruebaBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PruebaType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('descripcion');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PruebaBundle\Entity\Prueba',
            'attr' => array('id' => 'prueba_form',
                            'novalidate' => 'novalidate'
                           )
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'pruebabundle_prueba';
    }


}
```

NewView:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Prueba creation</h1>

    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    <div>
        {{ form_label(form.descripcion) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.descripcion) }} {{ form_errors(form.descripcion) }}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('prueba_index') }}">Back to the list</a>
        </li>
    </ul>


{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}            
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $form = $('#prueba_form');
            $form.submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: $form.attr('action'),
                    type: $form.attr('method'),
                    data: $form.serialize(),

                    success: function (html) {
                        $form.html($(html).filter('#prueba_form'));
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("error" + data);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

ShowView:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Prueba</h1>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <td>{{ prueba.id }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <td>{{ prueba.descripcion }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('prueba_index') }}">Back to the list</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('prueba_edit', { 'id': prueba.id }) }}">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            {{ form_start(delete_form) }}
                <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            {{ form_end(delete_form) }}
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

It is a simple Symfony3 code, thanks for your help.

Comment: If the AJAX call returns a redirect it will redirect that AJAX call. Not the page the call came from. You need to instead return JSON and then handle that in your Javascript to then redirect the page.

Comment: Yes it would be a good solution but I rather like not to write much code and since it works correctly sometimes I think it would be better to take advantage of that behavior and keep the code simple and clear.

Comment: That literally makes no sense at all. If you return a redirect to an AJAX call then it will not redirect the page that made the AJAX call - you need more Javascript to make that work.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point, but in fact it redirects correctly after submitting wrong data and correct it and submit again. I'd like someone to try this code and see that strange behavior.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't redirect because this " if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {" returns false

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for your help,

I found that my code was completely wrong, at the first AJAX call I was replacing the form content whith another form (form into form), when that happend the second AJAX call failed because it was sending an empty form.

I changeg my View Javascript:

```
//...
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        observForm();
    });

    function observForm() {
        var $inputSubmit = $('#prueba_form :submit');
        $inputSubmit.on('click', function () {
            setClick();
            return false;
        });
    }

    function setClick() {
        var $form = $('#prueba_form');

        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: $form.serialize(),

            success: function (html) {
                if (html.startsWith('route::')) {
                    route = html.replace('route::', '');
                    location.href = route;
                } else {
                    $form.html($(html).filter('#prueba_form').html());
                    observForm();
                }

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("error" + data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And I also changed my controller:

```
//...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
//...
            //return $this->redirectToRoute('prueba_show', array('id' => $prueba->getId()));
            return new JsonResponse('route::'.$this->get('router')->generate('prueba_show', ['id' => $prueba->getId()]));
```